# jquery hover menu fadein/hide dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, html-lists

I have a little jquery

```
    $(".dropdown").hide();

$('#mainnav ul li').hover(function(e){
        $(this).children('.dropdown').fadeIn(250);
}, function(e) {
        $(this).children('.dropdown').hide();
});
```

This fades in and hides each menu drop down when it's parent LI is hovered over.

I'm not convinced this is jquery is robust enough.
Sometimes the dropdowns don't hide if the mouse is moved accross the parent li's at speed.

Is there anything I can do to improve the reliability of this code?

Thanks

Comment: Use [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: You could try:

`.stop().fadeIn(250);` and
`.stop().hide()`.

`stop()` will clear all the animation queue and execute the current one.

Answer (score 1):

as xFortyFourx mentioned, you can use `.stop()` method to clear the queue. As jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) says, stop method works only with animations, so you'd better use `.animate()` instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

```
$("#mainnav ul li").hover(
    function() {
         $(this).children('.dropdown').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown').stop().animate({opacity: 0});
    }
);
```

using `.stop()` with `.fadeIn()` will cause freezing elements at semi-transparent mode. See live preview of both situations here: http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/faqNt/

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help you :

```
    $(".dropdown").hide();
    $('#mainnav ul li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.dropdown').stop().fadeIn(250);
     }, function() {
        $(this).children('.dropdown').stop().hide();
    });
```

or

```
$('#mainnav ul li').hover(function(){
  if($(this).children('.dropdown').css('display') == 'none'){
     $(this).children('.dropdown').fadeIn(250);
  } else {
     $(this).children('.dropdown').stop().hide();
  }
});
```

Good luck

Comment: shouldn't the stop() be on the children because that's what is being animated